# Ubuntu Server working from public IP but not through Godaddy DNS record

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

So the ubuntu server I'm using for a webserver is acting fine when I try to ssh or view the page using it's public IP. However when I try to use the record I just created in GoDaddy it wont work. I am trying to set up a subdomain and it won't work at all. I just had the exact same setup working on Amazon's OS but I saw too many negative reviews of the distro. So I spun up some instances running ubuntu and immediately they aren't working.

I have the record set to type:'A' and the name and value are definitely set correctly.

What else should I check? I'm not sure where the error is here because the godaddy setup is so simple. I feel like it has to be in my setup of the EC2 instance or some other aws settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the site via public IP and you are sure that the A record config is fine, I think the dns is still being propagated. Dns propogation may take longer.

If that's the case, Give it some time.

You can check which part of world knows about your new cname on https://dnschecker.org/. There are many other sites as well.

Comment: I put it in and it looks like everywhere has the address correctly populated. The same exact address that you can use directly and it will work... Have I royally messed up something?

Comment: What happens when you ping to the cname, all I care is whether it resolves to an IP address when you ping

Comment: It just hangs but am not configured to actually get icmp packets anyways.

But i CAN ABSOLUTELY view the page using the ip address directly even though i CANNOT ping the ip address.

So pinging the cname doesn't work but it wouldn't anyways.

The weird thing to be is navigating to the cname doesn't work but navigating to the public ip DOES! How is this possible if the cname resolves correctly?

Comment: If you are sure that you have added the A record pointing to the IP correctly in the correct dns management website, only thing i can think is the propogation. Please give it some time. If the dns checker says it's propogated in  America, it doesn't means it's propogated all over America. So give it time.  If you have doubts try pinging from an ec2. I know ICMP disabled. But all I care is resolving to an IP address. Thanks